# Complex job using JobControl Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Is there an elegant way to specify a sequence of dependent jobs using JobControl?

Some loops are also included, and since there is a number of sequential jobs (8) it will make quite of mess just putting all of that in a single driver class that adds all of them to job control.

How to do it?

Comment: Thought about using Oozie?

Comment: I did, but it seems heavyweight for what I'm doing. Maybe that isn't the case considering all, but there are also loops, as I said, and as I am aware of that's not something to go for, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map1 -> Reduce1 -> Map2 -> Reduce2 -> Map3...

You can easily chain jobs together in this fashion by writing multiple driver methods, one for each job. Call the first driver method, which uses JobClient.runJob() to run the job and wait for it to complete. When that job has completed, then call the next driver method, which creates a new JobConf object referring to different instances of Mapper and Reducer, etc. The first job in the chain should write its output to a path which is then used as the input path for the second job. This process can be repeated for as many jobs are necessary to arrive at a complete solution to the problem

A Job takes a JobConf object as its constructor argument. Jobs can depend on one another through the use of the addDependingJob() method. The code:

```
 x.addDependingJob(y)
```

says that Job x cannot start until y has successfully completed. Dependency information cannot be added to a job after it has already been started. Given a set of jobs, these can be passed to an instance of the JobControl class. JobControl can receive individual jobs via the addJob() method, or a collection of jobs via addJobs()

For Example:-
If We have three jobs A,B and C the sequence being A -> B -> C

```
ControlledJob AJob= new ControlledJob(JobConf for A);
ControlledJob BJob= new ControlledJob(JobConf for B);
BJob.addDependingJob(AJob);
ControlledJob CJob= new ControlledJob(JobConf for C);
CJob.addDependingJob(BJob);

JobControl jControl = newJobControl("Name");
jControl.addJob(AJob);
jControl.addJob(BJob);
jControl.addJob(CJob);

Thread runJControl = new Thread(jControl);
runJControl.start();
while (!jControl.allFinished()) {
code = jControl.getFailedJobList().size() == 0 ? 0 : 1;
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
System.exit(1);
```

We can have separate getters to get the JobConf for each of the jobs which has all the information of the job. Sample code for getter is as below:-

```
public static Configuration getAJobConf(Configuration conf, Path ip, Path op)throws IOException {
        final Job AJob = new Job(conf, "name");

        AJob.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        AJob.setInputFormatClass(InputFormat.class);
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(AJob, ip);

        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(AJob, op);
        AJob.setOutputFormatClass(tOutputFormat.class);

        AJob.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
        AJob.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
        AJob.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        AJob.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        AJob.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        AJob.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        AJob.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        return AJob.getConfiguration();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but as a asked in a question, is there a more elegant way to do it? You haven't shown the part where you have to configure the job actually (mapperClass, reducerClass, inputPath, outputPath, mapOutputKey, mapOutputValue, outputKey, outputValue, jobName...), and this could be quite of mess if you have larger number of jobs?

Comment: Hi Pera, I have edited in my answer itself. For each of the job I will be having separate getters which I will be passing in the controlled job argument. Able to run 10 map reduce jobs in a sequence.

Comment: Thanks, not bad. This way I'll have 10 getters, but I must have this boilerplate code somewhere, don't I. :) Thank you again, I'll wait a bit to see maybe some other idea, before accepting your answer.

Comment: Actually, I haven't. :) So I'm accepting your answer, thanks for reminding me.